# Dependency resolution in large multi project gradle builds

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a large multiproject build, which has a separate master folder containing a buildSrc dir which builds a gradle plugin that defines our packaging system.  One of the tasks I have conceived is to use an sqlite db to act as a source of data during the build of the individual projects.  So in buildSrc/build.gradle I have a repository defined that has the sqlite jar, and define the jar dependency in the dependencies block as

```
implementation 'org.sqlite:sqlite-jdbc:3.25.2'
```

This allows unit tests in buildSrc to complete successfully proving that the jar was downloaded and used successfully.  I have a gradle plugin defined in buildSrc which adds two tasks, one to apply sql files found inside the project (it does via command line), and another which queries the database using

```
sqlite = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlite:"+dbLocation.absolutePath, "org.sqlite.JDBC")
sqlite.rows(query).each { row ->
  sb.append(row.toString() + "\n") 
}
```

The problem is that this second task fails with an exception

```
  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlitejdbc:sqlite:/var/folders/vh/_gy4rj65695108sd5fpcqfd00000gn/T/sqlite1762555617470507686.db
```

As you can see, I define the connection string using the absolute path of a temp file

**THINGS I'VE TRIED:**

Immediately after the above error, I can see that the file exists

```
$ ls /var/folders/vh/_gy4rj65695108sd5fpcqfd00000gn/T/sqlite1762555617470507686.db
/var/folders/vh/_gy4rj65695108sd5fpcqfd00000gn/T/sqlite1762555617470507686.db
```

I mention this as it's one of the things to be sure of, to make sure the file wasn't deleted for some reason and it's not.  I also run a dependencies gradle command to see the list of jars resolved or not from a subproject dir;

```
$ ../../master/gradlew dependencies --configuration implementation --configure-on-demand     …     implementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
+--- org.sqlite:sqlite-jdbc:3.25.2 (n)
\--- project rpm-base (n)

(n) - Not resolved (configuration is not meant to be resolved)
```

Interestingly I see it is resolved for other configurations, infact all other configurations except implementation are resolved without the (n)

```
runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
+--- org.sqlite:sqlite-jdbc:3.25.2
```

I believe my problem is related to the (n) in the dependency command output, any help appreciated.  I've poured through google output, stackoverflow and used chatgpt for suggestions and nothing has worked thus far.

Thank you for your consideration and valuable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not resolve this using java drivers, I instead opted to use command line for all database queries.

```
String runCommand(String si, String cmd){
    def sout = new StringBuilder()
    def serr = new StringBuilder()
    
    println si + "Running $cmd"
    def procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder()
    procBuilder.environment()['SHELL'] = '/bin/bash'
    procBuilder.environment()['GRADLE_EXIT_CONSOLE'] = 'true'
    procBuilder.command('/bin/bash' , "-c", "$cmd")
    def proc = procBuilder.start()
    proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
    proc.waitForOrKill(30000)
    if (serr.length() > 0){
        throw new GradleException(serr.toString())
    }
    return sout
}
String cmd = 'sqlite3 '+dbLocation+' ".mode json" "'+query+'" ".exit"'
```